# Trying to show divs at bottomwhile hovering over menu items

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at the codes (HTML and CSS) and please let me know how can I hover over one menu item and them the corresponding divs appear at the bottom. Let me know what is wrong with my code!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Trying to show a div while hover over menu items</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        .menu_div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:red;
        display: block;}

        .menu_div ul li {list-style: none; display:inline-block;}

        .show_div ul li {display: inline-block;}

        .show_div_one {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: none;
        }
        .show_div_two {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: none;
        }
        .menu_div ul li.menu_item_one:hover + .show_div ul li.show_div_one{display:block;}
        .menu_div ul li.menu_item_two:hover + .show_div ul li.show_div_two{display:block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu_div">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu_item_one">
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item_two">
            <a href="">about</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="show_div">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="show_div_one">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="show_div_two">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain more clearly what you are after? what action are you after when you hover over menu_div element?

Comment: Not possible with the current HTML structure. The hovered `li` do not share a parent with `div` to be shown so your code will not work. I recommend a JS/JQ solution.

Comment: I recommend reading up on some JQuery, it will allow you to do slide-down effects. The way I would handle what you are trying to do would be to use a JQuery effect, on mouseenter you use the slideDown function which will reveal your div, and on mouseleave you use the slideUp function to hide the div again, this will give your site a 'flow' to it instead of jumpy hide and reveal effects. That being said, I don't see a way to do what you want without Javascript or Jquery.

Comment: @Harry, I want to hover over a menu item (e.g: Home) and want a div appear bellow the home button, and so on for other menu items as well.

Comment: @Paulie_d, can you please tell me what will be the correct code?

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS selectors, although they may seem to be logically using the `+` adjacency operator, in fact, arent.

The direct adjacency selector is for DOM elements that come directly after one another. In your HTML, in order to reach the elements you wish to show you have to first traverse the DOM 'upward' to the parent `menu_div` element, then across to its sibling `show_div` and then down to the correct child. CSS cannot do this.

[**More on this from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

> (+) This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only
>   the specified element that *immediately follows* the former specified
>   element.

You will need to change your code per the below, to place the element you wish to show immediately following the element you wish to hover on, you may also want to control its positioning by setting `position:absolute`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TYhnb/827/)

```
<div class="menu_div">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu_item_one"> <a href="">Home</a>

            <div class="show_div_one">show me!</div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item_two"> <a href="">about</a>

            <div class="show_div_two">show me!</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .menu_div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color:red;
      display: block;
  }
  .menu_div ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display:inline-block;
  }
  .show_div ul li {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .show_div_one, .show_div_two {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: orange;
      margin-top: 50px;
      display: none;
      position:absolute; /* <--- keep the flow you anticipate */
  }
  .menu_div ul li.menu_item_one a:hover + .show_div_one {
      display:block;
  }
  .menu_div ul li.menu_item_two a:hover + .show_div_two {
      display:block;
  }
```

Comment: it works fine, Thanks, but where does this CSS code comes from:.show_div ul li {
      display: inline-block;

Comment: @user3812012 - its in your original code in your question

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JQuery as this will be far better than relying on CSS alone.

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/y6bH7/)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
     $('.show_div_one').hide();

    $('.menu_item_one').hover(
    function(){  
        $('.show_div_one').show();
    },
    function(){  
        $('.show_div_one').hide();
    }                 
    );
});
```

Not tested, but thats the general idea for each one you would want to appear and disappear based on hover.